# Reset password MacAir

Tags: ios11

Just upgraded to iOS 11 and reset password and I can login with Apple ID onto phones but not on MacAir. In MacAir reset admin password mode and every time I try to enter password it messages back with “server error. Try signing in again”. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

hold Cmd + R on boot its recovery
and next type full `mount -uw / && rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone && shutdown -r now` or step by step